# Hide container, but show content

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm trying to quickly create a print style sheet where I'd like to remove an element from being printed, but still force a child element.

```
<div class="container print-hide">
   <p class="content print-show">
      Some content
   </p>
</div>
```

I was hoping the CSS gurus out there would have a better idea than myself.  In this case, I want to strip all the styling of an element (in this case the container), but still show the nested element (content).

```
@media print {
   .print-hide { display:none; }
   .print-show { /* magic */ }
}
@media screen {
}
```

---

I can only quickly think of 3 approaches, all of which are not desired:

1. Embed double the content in the HTML.  With the nested elements that have the class *print-show* displayed where they would be rendered, and hide them in the screen view.
2. Use JS and open the content in a new window / iframe, stripping out the elements we want to print
3. Don't use classes and strip the parts I don't like in the CSS:

   ```
   @media print{
      .container { /* remove unwanted styling */ }
   }
   ```

Comment: Really thinking this is not possible, since it would go against the natural structure of CSS any element with `display:none` applies to the descendants, the descendants can't override the ancestor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't work. You can do specific tricks though.

If `container` has a background, you can make the background transparent. You could 'undo' other styling in a similar fashion.

If `container` has other content, you could wrap that content in spans or divs and hide those. If it contains just text, you could make the `font-size: 0`, and set the `font-size` of `content` to a specific size (or `1rem` for default).

But all those possiblities are just work-arounds for the fact that you can't hide a parent while keeping the child visible, so basically I think `option 3` is the best option you have.